# Retrieving String value from Parse Table

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

This should be fairly simple. I have a class called "Inventory". I have two important columns. "productName" and "productPrice". I need to get the productPrice based on the productName. How would I query for the name and then retrieve the associated price? The String is always returned as null.

**Update:**

```
 @Override
    public String getCost() {
        final String[] productValue = {null};
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>
        query.whereEqualTo("productName", Capris);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) { //no exception, hence success
                    productValue[0] = list.get(0).getString("productPrice");
                }
            }
        });
        return productValue[0];
    }
```

This is more or less what I now have. Is there a better way to return a string? It's still coming back as null. I just need to return the value from the query.

**Working Answer:**

[Returning String from Parse.com query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705660/returning-string-from-parse-com-query)

This was resolved in another question. In above code productValue[0] may be null as its an aysnc call So replace findInBackground with find()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this .....

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Inventory");
    query.whereEqualTo("productName", Capris);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
            for (ParseObject myData : list) {
            String user = (String) myData.get("productPrice");
            }
        }
        else {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                         "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              }
         }
    }
```

U can use String / int  ... what ever data ur retrieving ....

Comment: It won't let me return the String because "done" is void! But I can't change void to String because it would require refactoring core Parse files. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Y ur returning inside 'done' ! .... Ur getting ur value to Eg: 'user' .... This complete query take into one method (function) and return at the end of the method ...

Comment: Check the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705660/returning-string-from-parse-com-query

Answer (score 2):

`productCost` is a class of Parse Object Type. You are converting it to string when you should be rather accessing the member variable of class which contains the `productValue`. You should use something like this:

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects,
                ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                for (ParseObject productCost : objects) {
                   // use productCost.get(' product value columnName') to access the properties of the productCost object.
                }
            } else {
                //Query failed. There is an error
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: The problem is I still have to return a String containing the dollar value for the item in my database because I need extend that information to the general product class.